# React list removes wrong item when trying to delete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I created a todo list using React, everything works fine until I tried to implement a delete function.

Whenever I try to delete an item, React would delete everything else but that item instead. I checked my code and I couldn't figure out what might be the cause. Console log returns the correct object when an item is click. I have a feeling that this might have to do with the key value not being unique or how my code is factored. To better illustrate the problem I encountered, I've created a [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/6130nmwlmk).

[image: Edit 6130nmwlmk]

Comment: Functionally, your delete is deleting all elements *except* the one you clicked the delete on.

Comment: you may concat somethings with your key value to make key unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`splice()` actually does two things, in practice it sort of has a side effect *and* a return. You were expecting the original array to return (understandably) but splice() actually returns the array of the items **chopped** from the initial array ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)). So the variable `tasks` was being set to an array of todo list items chopped out of the initial state of todo list items.

What you want is essentially just the side effect. You can see an updated CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/8zwlvvr5ql), but all I did was create a copy of the current state, then use splice() on that copy -- at which point we're only using the side-effect aspect of splice().

```
const tasks = this.state.tasks.slice(); // copy of current todo list
tasks.splice(index, 1); // "splice" out the list item we want to delete, but don't return a new list

this.setState({ tasks });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I understand the problem now!

Comment: My pleasure! Splice() is super useful, but also definitely a "gotcha" for this exact reason

Answer (score 4):

This is because your `deleteHandler` in the `Todo` component uses `.splice` ... which [returns the removed element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Your code:

```
  deleteHandler = index => {
    const tasks = this.state.tasks.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      tasks
    });
  };
```

You want to do something like in [this codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/x7oo8r9n7p).

```
  deleteHandler = index => {
    const newTasks = this.state.tasks.filter((task, tIndex) => {
      return index !== tIndex;
    });
    this.setState({
      tasks: newTasks
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, your delete function is working as expected: return updated state.tasks which contains an element you clicked. Use this instead:

```
deleteHandler = index => {
    this.setState({
      tasks: this.state.tasks.filter((task) => task.value !== index)
    });
  };
```

It works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your deleteHandler Funtion with this.

```
deleteHandler = index => {
   const tasks = this.state.tasks.slice();
   tasks.splice(index, 1);
   this.setState({
      tasks
   });
};
```

It's better approach when set/reset/modify state you must create a copy of state by using slice method then delete from the copied list then setState.